# Drive value to follow path while driving object?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, constraints, drivers

I’m working in a portable conveyors like this:

[image]
*Source: https://youtu.be/I1LRYNS4ndo*

I used copy rotation to expand it and a driver to active it, but I don't know how to make it follow the bezier curve to use the spline IK, also maybe I need another bone for the other end of the conveyor. [Link to the project file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PXgTmE3zyqHKm1lfdBBSd3eqVZGXuHcN/view?usp=sharing)

**Q:** How to make the conveyor follow a bezier curve considering the spline IK?

Comment: thank you, now its better